# Django Template Foreign Key Check

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

In **model:**

```
class Example
    text

class Share
    example (foreign_key)
    user    (foreign_key)
```

In **view:**

```
def page:
    items = Example.objects.get(user=user)
    user_shares = Example.objects.get(user=user)
    return render(page.html, {'items': items, 'user_shares': user_shares})
```

In the template I can show items in rows. But for the ***shared ones*** I want to put for example additional buttons.
How can I use **something like** `{% if item in shares %}` in for loop? Or do you have *better ideas*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the template:

```
{% for item in items %}
<td>{{item.text}}</td>
{%if item.shares.count > 0 %}
<td><!-- additional buttons here --></td>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

you need to modify the `ForeignKey` in the `Example` model:

```
class Share(models.Model):
    example = models.ForeignKey(Example, related_name='shares')
    ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use `item.shares.exists` instead of `item.shares.count > 0`.

Comment: You saved me 4 years later.